# Getting 'Data Not Found' Error in Oracle Trigger While Using Spring @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, plsql, triggers

I have a method with multiple database inserts inside it, and I've added the `@Transactional` annotation to it. One of the tables has a trigger that updates a history table when inserting records into it. However, I'm encountering a 'Data Not Found' error. This error occurs because the trigger tries to execute before all insert actions are complete, and it attempts to retrieve newly inserted data from a table.

I'm using java spring project and oracle db.

I want to execute the trigger after all insertions commited

Here's the relevant trigger code:

```sql
create or replace trigger TRIG_TRANS_DATA
after insert or update on tbl_ms_v_value
for each row
declare
    V_Header tbl_vv_header%ROWTYPE;
    V_Amount tbl_vv_vehi_val.AMOUNT%TYPE;
    V_Details  tbl_vv_detail%ROWTYPE;
    V_Cost tbl_vv_cost.TRAVEL_COST%TYPE;
    V_Tr_Amount tbl_vv_trans.TOTAL_AMOUNT%TYPE;
begin
    if inserting or updating then
        select * into V_Header from tbl_vv_header where header_v_id = :NEW.value_v_id;
        -- rest of the trigger logic
    end if;
end;
```

```java
@Override
    @Transactional
    public int saveVDataDetails(VFormDetailsDTO detailsDTOData){
//logic
vDataDAO.save(vData);
//logic
vDataDAO.save(vformData);
//logic
vDataDAO.save(vValueformData);
return 1;
}
```

I'm using java spring project and oracle db.

I want to execute the trigger after all insertions commited

Comment: I don't know Java. Though, it looks as if trigger isn't the right choice to do what you're doing. It fires **for each row**, so perhaps you'd rather create a **procedure** (just reuse code from that trigger; pass ID value to it as a parameter).